# Find net cumulative return from my Investment Report for a 3 month period

Tags: stocks, investing, united-kingdom, shares, portfolio

I have an Investment Report for a 3 month period that shows me:

- Number of Shares
- Book Cost
- Market Price
- Market Value
- Estimated Income
- Estimated Yield
- Total Value %

How do I work out the cumulative return for that 3 month period?

Comment: Is there something in particular you are planning on doing with that information? This will impact whether a simplistic or most accurate approach is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way to determine the return of an asset is to take the ending value and divide it by the starting value**. Let's build that up in terms of how complex you may want to get:

1) If you start with $100 in the bank, they pay you $2 in interest, and you end the year with $102. 102 / 100 = 102%, and after subtracting the 100% you started with, this is a 2% return.

2) If you start with 100 shares worth $1 each, and at the end of the year they are worth $1.05 each, your return is $105 / $100 - 1 = 5%.

3) If you have shares that pay dividends, and you have interest-earning assets, the formula is (ending value of all assets, including cash received as dividends and interest ) / (opening value of all assets when you started the account) - 1. So if scenario #1 & #2 were both correct, you ended the year with $207 in value and started with $200 in value, so the return would be 207/200 - 1 = 3.5%.

4) Further, that return above is 'simplistic', not 'annualized'. If you had a 3.5% return over 3 months, then we could simplistically multiply that by 4, to represent the expected return over a whole year, and 3.5% * 4 = 14%.

5) Finally, the method in #4 above doesn't consider "compounding"; so technically your return would be higher over the whole year, because the earnings in the 1st 3 months would continue to earn income, and the earnings in the next 3 months would also earn income, etc. The formula for this is (return over a length of time + 1) ^ (how many of those lengths of time you are considering) [ie 12 months in a year, 4 quarters in a year, 365 days in a year, etc.] -1.

So for a 3 month return where you need to account for 4 of those periods to get a yearly return, the formula would be: (3 month return + 1) ^ (4) - 1. So 1.035^4 - 1 = 14.75%. For most purposes if you just want a simple approximation of return, method in #4 above will be close.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy.

It is made harder by there being several measures of return. One is money-weighted rate of return and the other is time-weighted rate of return.

If you did not make any changes, the return is `100*(market_value_now / market_value_3mo_ago - 1)`. This formula requires that there are no dividends, or that you wish to exclude dividends from the calculated return.

However, for the `market_value_3mo_ago` you need your report from 3 months before the current report.

If you made changes to the portfolio or got dividends, please not that then time-weighted rate of return is different from money-weighted rate of return.